How do i get github to report a top level job status?
I have a job that looks like this:
on:
  pull_request:
  merge_group:

jobs:
  stg:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'merge_group' }}
    name: Build and Deploy Stage
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-deploy.yml

In my branch protection rules, i have it required that Build and Deploy Stage has to pass before merging, and there is a merge queue enabled. That stage has a condition that it will skip on the PR, so that it only deploys to stage after it's in the merge queue and before it merges.
When I have a PR, it correctly shows Build and Deploy Stage as a skipped job. However, once it gets into the merge queue, it only wants to show the status of the sub-jobs like Build and Deploy Stage / build. (see image)
If I require Build and Deploy Stage / build instead, then the PR will never be added to the merge queue, because at the PR stage, it is never evaluated.
Can I force the top level job to report somehow in the merge queue?

